# Angular directive not getting instantiated

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a simple popover directive in angular but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not sure why but the directive doesn't seem to get instantiated - I'm not even getting the console.log back:

```
var core = angular.module('core', []);
core.directive('popover', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        var isTouchDevice = !!("ontouchstart" in window);
        console.log(isTouchDevice);
        if (isTouchDevice) {
            el.bind("touchstart", function (e) {
                console.log('on mobile');
            });
        } else {
           el.bind("mouseover", function (e) {
              console.log('on desktop');
          });   
        }
      }
   };
});
```

Using it with the following html:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div popover>hover me</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nv8eq7n8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not to wrap the script inside the document on `jsfiddle` (see the upper-left menu, I set it to `no wrap - in <body>`). Otherwise, the DOM would be loaded before the JS, and thus you get the missing module error.

And yes, as the other answer said, you need to specify the app name.

Here it is, working all fine: http://jsfiddle.net/wx8ydotr/

Answer (score 2):

You missed the app's name:
`<div ng-app="core">`

It seems the code isn't loading, i had to change the html to:

```
<script>
    var core = angular.module('core', []);
    core.directive('popover', function() {
        return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            var isTouchDevice = !!("ontouchstart" in window);
            console.log(isTouchDevice);
            if (isTouchDevice) {
              el.bind("touchstart", function (e) {
                  console.log('on mobile');
              });
            } else {
               el.bind("mouseover", function (e) {
                  console.log('on desktop');
              });   
            }
        }
        };
    });
</script>
<div ng-app="core">
    <div popover>hover me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. That just gives Failed to instantiate module core due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'core' is not available! Check the fiddle above

Comment: SergioFilhow is right, but the script is not loaded before the html is instantiated.

Comment: yea, the script is not loading, maybe you should put an <script> tag on your html to load the js file. I editted my answer with the code I had to run in order to execute correctly

Comment: It's jsfiddle's onload JS wrapper... the JS is simply not loaded before the DOM is processed.